Would a Gazebo Harmonic plugin meant to simulate a RGB-D camera inherit from gz::sim::System or gz::sim::Sensors?
Recently, I have had some success in forward porting Clearpath Robotics Gazebo simulator from Gazebo Classic to Gazebo Harmonic (can successfully launch a Husky in a blank world, will be releasing it soon).
When simulating the Husky, the system configurator utilizes pal-robotics realsense_gazebo_plugin and the mesh files from realsense2_description packages to generate a realsense camera asset.
However, the above two packages were last tested with Gazebo Classic and ROS 2 Foxy.
I have begun a fork of realsense_gazebo_plugin package to make it compatible with ROS 2 Jazzy and Gazebo Harmonic: https://github.com/Mechazo11/realsense_gazebo_plugin
So far, I have figured out how to change the package dependencies and CmakeLists.txt file. But I now have a number of questions with the first one shown below

In the ROS 2 version of the realsense_gazebo_plugin, the core class, RealSensePlugin is defined as the following


class RealSensePlugin : public ModelPlugin
{
  /// \brief Constructor.

public:
  RealSensePlugin();

  /// \brief Destructor.
  ~RealSensePlugin();

  // Documentation Inherited.
  virtual void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf);

  /// \brief Callback for the World Update event.
  void OnUpdate();

  /// \brief Callback that publishes a received Depth Camera Frame as an
  /// ImageStamped
  /// message.
  virtual void OnNewDepthFrame();

  /// \brief Callback that publishes a received Camera Frame as an
  /// ImageStamped message.
  virtual void OnNewFrame(
    const rendering::CameraPtr cam,
    const transport::PublisherPtr pub);

According to this migration guide: https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/migrationplugins.html
the RealSensePlugin now needs to be like the following
class RealSensePlugin : public gz::sim::System,
                        public gz::sim::ISystemConfigure,
                        public gz::sim::ISystemPostUpdate

my question is should I be inheriting from the above three methods or will be it gz::sensors::DepthCameraSensor from here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/gz-sensors9/include/gz/sensors/DepthCameraSensor.hh
Thank you for your time.
With best regards,
Azmyin

I'm not sure if it's necessary to create a plugin for this. Have you considered just using the built-in depth cameras in Gazebo?

Hi Dr. @azeey, No I haven't tried the built in plugins yet. I thought Realsense cameras are RGB-D sensors hence it would require a custom plugin to enable both RGB and Depth cameras instead of manually placing a RBG plugin and a Depth camera plugin. Would you suggest I just manually place a camera and depth plugin in the robot's xacro file? If latter is the case, I am curious to know why a custom plugin, such as Realsense was required for gazebo classic.

Gazebo has a camera type called rgbd_camera (see http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.11&elem=sensor) which will publish rgbd data. So you just need to place one camera and set its type to rgbd_camera. Take a look at https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/990f1c27d4f2ef69740bab433be6e8b7206d39ac/examples/worlds/sensors_demo.sdf#L452. If you're using it with ROS, here's a launch file that sets up the topic bridging for ROS https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/blob/ros2/ros_gz_sim_demos/launch/rgbd_camera.launch.py

Thanks, I will report back when I am able to try these plugins out if they solve the above problem
